# get data from same table in sql using join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I have a table [dbo].[UserImages] where user uploads their photos after every 6 day, total 18 records for user 3. 9 records of day 1 and 9 records of day 6. There are 4 columns In this table 
`[Id, UserId, Image, Day]`

```
Id  UserId  Image               Day
1   3       3_20200408_1.png    1
2   3       3_20200408_2.png    1
3   3       3_20200408_3.png    1
4   3       3_20200408_4.png    1
5   3       3_20200408_5.png    1
6   3       3_20200408_6.png    1
7   3       3_20200408_7.png    1
8   3       3_20200408_8.png    1
9   3       3_20200408_9.png    1
10  3       3_20200410_9.png    6
11  3       3_20200410_2.png    6
12  3       3_20200410_3.png    6
13  3       3_20200410_4.png    6
14  3       3_20200410_5.png    6
15  3       3_20200410_6.png    6
16  3       3_20200410_7.png    6
17  3       3_20200410_8.png    6
18  3       3_20200410_9.png    6
```

I need something like that

`ImgCount      UserId   ImageDay1           ImageDay6
1               3       3_20200408_1.png    3_20200408_1.png
2               3       3_20200408_2.png    3_20200408_2.png
3               3       3_20200408_3.png    3_20200408_3.png
4               3       3_20200408_4.png    3_20200408_4.png
5               3       3_20200408_5.png    3_20200408_5.png
6               3       3_20200408_6.png    3_20200408_6.png
7               3       3_20200408_7.png    3_20200408_7.png
8               3       3_20200408_8.png    3_20200408_8.png
9               3       3_20200408_9.png    3_20200408_9.png`

What should I do for this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select
    imgCount,
    userId,
    max(case when day = 1 then image end) ImageDay1,
    max(case when day = 6 then image end) ImageDay6
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by userId, day order by image) imgCount
    from mytable t
    where day in (1, 6)
) t
group by userId, imgCount
order by ImgCount
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9622063654f3e70a784420e0dc17bb0e)**:

```
ImgCount | userId | ImageDay1        | ImageDay6       
:------- | -----: | :--------------- | :---------------
1        |      3 | 3_20200408_1.png | 3_20200410_1.png
2        |      3 | 3_20200408_2.png | 3_20200410_2.png
3        |      3 | 3_20200408_3.png | 3_20200410_3.png
4        |      3 | 3_20200408_4.png | 3_20200410_4.png
5        |      3 | 3_20200408_5.png | 3_20200410_5.png
6        |      3 | 3_20200408_6.png | 3_20200410_6.png
7        |      3 | 3_20200408_7.png | 3_20200410_7.png
8        |      3 | 3_20200408_8.png | 3_20200410_8.png
9        |      3 | 3_20200408_9.png | 3_20200410_9.png
```

Comment: Its returning all 18 records

Comment: @arvind above query returns the way you expected. check it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/671d9/13

Comment: @arvind: this works as expected. I added a fiddle to my answer for your reference.